# VS2017 Cordova $.ajax XMLHTTPREQUEST FAILED

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, visual-studio-cordova

The code works when testing with a browser. But failed when I build and install the apk.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "http://localhost:60052/Public/Interface.asmx/Test",
    data: JSON.stringify(Params),
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
    },
    error: function (XHR, errStatus, errorThrown) {
            // NETWORKERROR: 'XMLHTTPREQUEST': FAILED TO LOAD ......
    }
});
```

In my Cordova project, I have already set:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http:*" />
```